# Grails Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

Tags: hibernate, grails

This isn't actual code but code to just recreate the error i am trying to understand.

```
    //if this question has options
    if(question.options){

        //deleting all the options first
        def l = []
        l += question.options

        l.each { option ->
            question.removeFromOptions(option)
            option.delete(flush: true)
            }

    }



    //saving new options from the form
    if(params.options){

        for(po in params.options){

            question.addToOptions(new QuestionOptionSurvey(optionText: po))

        }

    }
```

So, the first section deletes existing options belonging to the question and the second part adds the new options to the question. Please note that this chunk belongs to a service method. So, the error thrown is "Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)". I know there are already posts regarding this issue but even after reading the docs and not being able to make sense i have come here for simpler explanation on the reason for this error. Why does grails or hibernate prevent me from first deleting options and then updating new options? i appreciate any help.

Comment: Try to use  withNewTransaction{}

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
//saving new options from the form
if(params.options) {

    def options = []
    for(po in params.options){

        options << new QuestionOptionSurvey(optionText: po)

    }

   question.options = options

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should have been a comment but I don't have 50 reps. 
If you have log that uses the properties of the object you are saving try removing that (even if it comes before the save).